# How to journal tables in SQL?

Tags: db2, db2-midrange

Say I have a C# script that creates 50 tables in MYLIB.

Currently, after running the script, I have to go into System i Navigator and manually attach the MYLIB/USRJRN to each of the tables' journaling.

How can I make my script do this instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may start DB2 table journaling with the [QSYS2.QCMDEXC](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_72/rzajq/rzajqprocqcmdexc.htm) procedure and a corresponding text of the [STRJRNPF](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_72/cl/strjrnpf.htm) CL command as an argument. Something like this:

```
CALL QSYS2.QCMDEXC('STRJRNPF FILE(MYFILELIB/MYFILENAME) JRN(MYLIB/USRJRN) IMAGES(*BOTH) OMTJRNE(*OPNCLO)');
```

Comment: It works! Sort of. Only downside I see is that it will only work with the SYSTEM_TABLE_NAME, not the TABLE_NAME. Though, that can be fixed by a simple select from QSYS2.SYSTABLES. Is there a way to make it work directly with (longer than 10 characters) TABLE_NAME, though?

Comment: No afaik. So, it's better to create a stored procedure generating an appropriate command and calling QSYS2.QCMDEXEC routine based on TABLE_SCHEMA & TABLE_NAME user input.

Answer (score 0):

If you create your library via the SQL `CREATE SCHEMA` command, then it will include a journal and journal receivers and all tables created in it will automatically be journaled.

Also, IBM offers the [Start Journal Library (STRJRNLIB)](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_72/cl/strjrnlib.htm) command which lets you start default journaling on an existing library.

See also [Automatically starting journaling](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_72/rzaki/rzakiautostrjrnl.htm) for information about using QDFTJRN to start automatically start journaling.